# Combine Array Keys PHP

Tags: php

I have an array that can contain one more more key.  What I would like to do is if there are more than one key for that array to comma separate the two values

I need to enter 6,7 in a database field where order number is 23489, but not sure how to go about that.  All the others are okay in this instance as they only have the one key.

```
array
  239489 => 
    array
      0 => string '6' (length=1)
      1 => string '7' (length=1)
  329048 => 
    array
      0 => string '10' (length=2)
  908423 => 
    array
      0 => string '11' (length=2)
  '239489-1' => 
    array
      0 => string '8' (length=1)
```

Comment: You might want to clarify the question.

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to enter "6,7" into any database field. You may want to look at normalizing your database structure first?

Comment: Hold on and think about your database schema.  While this might seem like an easy solution to your current problem, it is likely to cause you endless headaches down the road, as you have to deal with your improperly normalized data.  Really, since there's the possibility of multiple values per key, you should be storing the values in another table with a one-to-many relationship to the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop should comma separate if the sub array contains more than one key,

```
foreach($main_arr as $k=>$sub_arr) {
   if(count($sub_arr)>1) {
       $main_arr[$k] = implode(',', $sub_arr);
   }
}
```

Comment: I dislike this answer for a few reasons: 1) At the end of the loop, you'll have a mixed-type array; some elements will be comma-separated strings, some will be single element arrays. This makes for more complex processing later. 2) Why the alternate syntax; just use curly-braces. 3) `if` statements without braces are asking for trouble.

Comment: I agree!! Curly braces are Awesome. I just gave him the idea. Will make the changes right away

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $array[$key] = implode(',', $value);
}
```

This will overwrite the arrays with an imploded string ... if you don't want to overwrite your original array, you could:

```
$orders = array();    
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $orders[$key] = implode(',', $value);
}
```

I will point out that storing comma-separated values in a database field is, generally, a design flaw ... you may want to consider something like an order_items table ... but that's just my opinion ...

Comment: That's not just your opinion; comma separated values in a column are almost always an anti-pattern :)